# Use dependants annotations as arguments for bean creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'd like to influence creation of beans by the annotations of dependants.
Specifically use annotations as arguments to the bean constructor (or inspect data in the annotations and generate the arguments)

This is similar to qualifiers, yet qualifiers never pass the qualification details to the bean, where as I would like to do that.

Example of what I'd like to do:

```java
@Component
public MyClass {
  @Autowired
  public MyClass(
    @KafkaSettings("topic1", site="aws")
    @KafkaSettings("topic7", site="gcp")
    MultiPublisher multiPublisher
  ) { ... }
}
```

where the publisher instantiation receives the arguments of the annotations and can act on them:

```java
public class MultiPublisher {
  public MultiPublisher(Target[] targets) { ... }
}

public class Target {
  public String topic;
  public String site;
}
```

and my application config has something like:

```
kafka:
  regions:
    aws:
      bootstrap: aws1,aws2,gcp3
    gcp: 
      bootstrap: gcp1,gcp2,gcp3
```

Obviously the MultiPublisher bean would not be a singleton.
This would be a library that then can be reused, hence I do not want:

1. To have to pass in a factory, and then instantiate things myself, I'd like the library to do that for me.
2. Have to define additional methods as the user of the library to drive the instantiation of the MultiPublisher.

Ideally this should work as it's shown.

It seems BeanFactory has a doResolveDependency method that has a handle on the descriptor and the bean definitions that is required, but it seems it's not possible to override/replace BeanFactory in the application, as it's essentially the application context.

There are no FactoryBean's that actually receive any details about who the bean is being instantiated for.

Is this possible?